# What makes function expressions return a value?

Tags: javascript

I know that function expressions resolve to a value (not to be confused with what they return [as others cleared up for me in another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891464/function-expressions-vs-function-declarations-return-value/50891876#50891876))—all functions return `undefined` by default), hence the word "expression," whereas function declarations don't. But I'm not sure what exactly is causing this discrepancy. My initial guess was that it is the variable assignment (given what's to the right of the assignment operator is always an expression [I think]), but function expressions don't require variable assignment. To my knowledge the only other difference (besides resolving to a value) between them and function declarations is that you can omit the function name in a function expression. I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Could you add a simple example code?

Comment: I think that would be unnecessary... It's something all function expressions do. But for those unfamiliar with function expressions, here's a doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: Where would the function declaration resolve to?

Comment: @Kaiido If I'm not mistaken a function declaration (as a statement) doesn't resolve to anything.

Comment: @Natalie yes, my point being that even if it did, there would be nothing to catch this return value. Just like the statement `;"foo";` nothing catches the return value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Refer :https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows#function-expression-vs-function-declaration

**A Function Expression is created when the execution reaches it and is usable from then on.**

Once the execution flow passes to the right side of the assignment let sum = function… – here we go, the function is created and can be used (assigned, called etc) from now on.

Function Declarations are different.

**A Function Declaration is usable in the whole script/code block.**

In other words, when JavaScript prepares to run the script or a code block, it first looks for Function Declarations in it and creates the functions. We can think of it as an “initialization stage”.

And after all of the Function Declarations are processed, the execution goes on.

As a result, a function declared as a Function Declaration can be called earlier than it is defined.

```
sayHi("John"); // Hello, John

function sayHi(name) {
  alert( `Hello, ${name}` );
}
```

The Function Declaration sayHi is created when JavaScript is preparing to start the script and is visible everywhere in it.

**…If it was a Function Expression, then it wouldn’t work:**

```
sayHi("John"); // error!

let sayHi = function(name) {  // (*) no magic any more
  alert( `Hello, ${name}` );
};
```

Function Expressions are created when the execution reaches them. That would happen only in the line (*). Too late.

**When a Function Declaration is made within a code block, it is visible everywhere inside that block. But not outside of it.**

Sometimes that’s handy to declare a local function only needed in that block alone. But that feature may also cause problems.

For instance, let’s imagine that we need to declare a function welcome() depending on the age variable that we get during runtime. And then we plan to use it some time later.

```
let age = prompt("What is your age?", 18);

// conditionally declare a function
if (age < 18) {

  function welcome() {
    alert("Hello!");
  }

} else {

  function welcome() {
    alert("Greetings!");
  }

}

// ...use it later
welcome(); // Error: welcome is not defined
```

That’s because a Function Declaration is only visible inside the code block in which it resides.

**Here’s another example:**

```
let age = 16; // take 16 as an example

if (age < 18) {
  welcome();               // \   (runs)
                           //  |
  function welcome() {     //  |
    alert("Hello!");       //  |  Function Declaration is available
  }                        //  |  everywhere in the block where it's declared
                           //  |
  welcome();               // /   (runs)

} else {

  function welcome() {     //  for age = 16, this "welcome" is never created
    alert("Greetings!");
  }
}

// Here we're out of curly braces,
// so we can not see Function Declarations made inside of them.

welcome(); // Error: welcome is not defined
```

What can we do to make welcome visible outside of if?

The correct approach would be to use a Function Expression and assign welcome to the variable that is declared outside of if and has the proper visibility.

**Now it works as intended:**

```
let age = prompt("What is your age?", 18);

let welcome;

if (age < 18) {

  welcome = function() {
    alert("Hello!");
  };

} else {

  welcome = function() {
    alert("Greetings!");
  };

}

welcome(); // ok now
```

Or we could simplify it even further using a question mark operator ?:

```
let age = prompt("What is your age?", 18);

let welcome = (age < 18) ?
  function() { alert("Hello!"); } :
  function() { alert("Greetings!"); };

welcome(); // ok now
```

Comment: "Once the execution flow passes to the right side of the assignment"--what about when there's no assignment? How does JS know it's an expression in that case?